# Modify wrapper function for a function with parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a wrapper function as

```
const wrap = (func) =>{
    return () => {
        try {
          return func();
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.message);
          return null;
        }
      };
}
```

how should i modify my wrapper function(wrap) to handle both the function call i.e one with param and other without param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass `args` to your wrapped function and accept them in the wrapper one:

```js
const wrap = (func) =>{
    return (...args) => {
        try {
          return func(...args);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.message);
          return null;
        }
      };
}
```

PS: **Peach** is not gross.

Comment: @Swarup Chavan It's called [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)